# Invoking JMETER through java code and running the JMX test file causing Xstream Security Exception

Tags: java, jmeter, jmx, xstream

But while doing the same I am getting "Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable." Below is the code snippet

```
package com.jmeter.runner;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class JMeterFromExistingJMX {

     public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {


         Class<?>[] classes = new Class[] { JMeterFromExistingJMX.class };
         XStream xStream = new XStream();
         XStream.setupDefaultSecurity(xStream);
         xStream.allowTypes(classes);   



            // JMeter Engine
            StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();


            // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
            JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("F:/Required_Setup_Softwares/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/jmeter.properties");
            JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("F:/Required_Setup_Softwares/apache-jmeter-3.3");
            JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
            JMeterUtils.initLocale();

            // Initialize JMeter SaveService
            SaveService.loadProperties();

            // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("F:/Required_Setup_Softwares/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/test.jmx");
            HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
            in.close();

            // Run JMeter Test
            jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
            jmeter.run();
        }   


}
```

While running I am getting the Xstream security error as below

```
Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.configure(StandardJMeterEngine.java:176)
    at com.jmeter.runner.JMeterFromExistingJMX.main(JMeterFromExistingJMX.java:46)
```

jmeter.configure(testPlanTree); this line causing the issue as internally its using Xstream. So i tried below code to overcome but its not working.

```
 Class<?>[] classes = new Class[] { JMeterFromExistingJMX.class };
         XStream xStream = new XStream();
         XStream.setupDefaultSecurity(xStream);
         xStream.allowTypes(classes);
```

Please help me with the same. I tried the below code as well but its too not working

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
// clear out existing permissions and set own ones
xstream.addPermission(NoTypePermission.NONE);
// allow some basics
xstream.addPermission(NullPermission.NULL);
xstream.addPermission(PrimitiveTypePermission.PRIMITIVES);
xstream.allowTypeHierarchy(Collection.class);
// allow any type from the same package
xstream.allowTypesByWildcard(new String[] {
    "com.your.package.**"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue, however your code looks a little bit flaky:

- Looking into `F:/Required_Setup_Softwares/apache-jmeter-3.3` it appears you're using [JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3)
- Looking into [SaveService.loadTree()](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/5c9dd1632e92ca197f818a1ee04f8f8af4bbc42e/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/save/SaveService.java#L421) function as per JMeter 3.3 it requires [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html), not the FileInputStream

So I would recommend the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure you have [JMeter 3.3 libraries](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core/3.3) in your project dependencies
2. Make sure you remove the below code:

   ```
   // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
   FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("F:/Required_Setup_Softwares/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/test.jmx");
   HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
   in.close();
   ```

   and substitute it with the following line:

   ```
   HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("F:/Required_Setup_Softwares/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/test.jmx"));
   ```
3. Perform a clean build of your project - the issue should go away.